# Unable to load DLL after Outlook Add-In is published

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, outlook-addin, ghostscript

I am working on an outlook 2010 add-in where I am using the GhostScriptSharp API (gsdll32.dll) in my project and am running into an issue where the application has troubles loading the DLL after it is published.

The plug-in works perfectly fine in debug mode in visual studio, but once I publish and install the plug-in, I am getting the following exception at runtime:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'gsdll32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

In the dll file properties I have the build action set to "content" and the Copy to Output Directory set to "copy always".  Also I have tried to place a copy of the gsdll32.dll file in the C:\Windows\System32 folder, but the problem still is present.

Has anyone come across this situation after publishing an app/or plug-in when using a dll?  Is there something clearly wrong that I am doing?

Comment: How did you install the add-in on the end user PCs?

Comment: Consider using the [GhostScriptSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GhostScriptSharp/) NuGet package.

Comment: The add-in is installed via the one click deployment installation, which is created with the publish wizard found under the "Debug" menu -> Publish, in VS 2012.  I am using the GhostScriptSharp NuGet package, but that requires GhostScript to be installed on the system.  I instead took the main dll file from the GhostScript install directory (gsdll32.dll) and imported it into my project so I could use the code functionality without having GhostScript installed. When I build and debug, the DLL is present in the \bin folder and the debug session works as expected, but when I publish the add-in,

Comment: it would appear that the gsdll32.dll is not being brought in with the rest of the source code, after installation.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you need to include that dll to the installer package.

Comment: that's where I am getting tripped up.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong or why the installer package is not picking up the DLL with everything else.

Comment: See [How to: Specify Which Files Are Published by ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx).

Comment: You could try to use Ghostscript.NET (https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET) which allows you to specify dll location: https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/CustomGsdllLocationSample.cs

Comment: You are aware that Ghostscript is an AGPL open source project ? What you are doing (copying just the DLL, not having GS installed) looks to me very much like a potential violation of the licence.

Comment: So what you are saying is, the only way for me to be properly using GhostScript, is if it is installed, and not "embedded" in the application in order to comply with the AGPL rules?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this working by installing GhostScript separately along side my plug-in, instead of attempting to embed the gsdll32.dll in the plug-in.  I also had to edit my windows "path" environment variable so that the GhostScriptSharp wrapper could access GhostScript.